# Switch between applications with multiple workspaces

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, workspaces, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

## Then

System: Ubuntu 16.04

I have 4 workspaces and in each of them one Firefox window and a Terminal. With Ubuntu 16.04 I could switch between them with `Alt + Tab` and it would always take the application in the current workspace. Only if I hovered over let's say the Terminal, it showed the other Terminals from the other workspaces and I was able to take a different one.

## Now

System: Ubuntu 18.04.1

If I select the Terminal in W1, then switch to W2, select Firefox in W2 and then press `Alt + Tab` it brings me back to the Terminal in W1.

Same goes for the icons in the Favorite bar. If I press them it only opens up all the possibilities as previews (and they are sometimes not that easy to distinguish). In Ubuntu 16.04 a click on the icon would open the application of the current workspace and a second click opens the 4 possibilities.

## Questions

Is it possible that a switch with `Alt + Tab` opens the application from the current workplace instead of the last selected one?

Is it possible that a click on the icons opens the application from the current workplace instead of a preview from all? Even a solution that would show the workspace of each preview would help me, atm there is no further information than the preview... (For example in my current view the first Terminal corresponds to the 3rd Workplace)